# Where is the apply method in the docs, for Scala collection factory objects?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Because I can write:

```
DoubleLinkedList(1,2,3,4)
```

I expected to find an `apply` method in the `DoubleLinkedList` companion object, but I see nothing in the [docs linked here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.DoubleLinkedList%24).  Where is it?  Or, why is it not there?

Comment: Are you using 2.9? For 2.10 this bug is fixed for months now...

Comment: Yup, I was using 2.10 but docs for 2.9 by mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going up in the hierarchy found it in [`GenericCompanion`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/generic/GenericCompanion.html). It looks to me like its not being shown may be a Scaladoc bug.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to file a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

If you read carefully the doc page you mention :

A generic implementation of the CanBuildFrom trait, which forwards all calls to apply(from) to the genericBuilder method of collection from, and which forwards all calls of apply() to the newBuilder method of this factory.